# .net core JwtBearerAuthentication not defined

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, jwt

I'm working with a token based system for the first time in asp.net core. I've followed this article:

https://stormpath.com/blog/token-authentication-asp-net-core

My startup.cs looks like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using blog.Persistence;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices.Webpack;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using AutoMapper;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;

namespace WebApplicationBasic
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

        public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddAutoMapper();

            services.AddDbContext<VegaDbContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default")));

            // Add framework services.
            services.AddMvc();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
             // secretKey contains a secret passphrase only your server knows
            var signingKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration.GetSection("TokenAuthentication:SecretKey").Value));

            var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                // The signing key must match!
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                IssuerSigningKey = signingKey,

                // Validate the JWT Issuer (iss) claim
                ValidateIssuer = true,
                ValidIssuer = "ExampleIssuer",

                // Validate the JWT Audience (aud) claim
                ValidateAudience = true,
                ValidAudience = "ExampleAudience",

                // Validate the token expiry
                ValidateLifetime = true,

                // If you want to allow a certain amount of clock drift, set that here:
                ClockSkew = TimeSpan.Zero
            };

            app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(new JwtBearerOptions
            {
                AutomaticAuthenticate = true,
                AutomaticChallenge = true,
                TokenValidationParameters = tokenValidationParameters
            });

            loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
            loggerFactory.AddDebug();

            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
                app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions {
                    HotModuleReplacement = true
                });
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseMvc(routes =>
            {
                routes.MapRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

                routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                    name: "spa-fallback",
                    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that `UseJwtBearerAuthentication` and `JwtBearerOptions` are undefined. What could be wrong? Do I need to get another nuget package?

Comment: Have you added a reference to the correct package??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yo need to add AddAuthentication in startup.
Add the following code

```
Services.AddAuthentication(x =>
        {
            x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        }).AddJwtBearer(o =>
        {
            var Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(settings.Key);
            o.SaveToken = true;
            o.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                ValidateIssuer = false,
                ValidateAudience = false,
                ValidateLifetime = true,
                ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                ValidIssuer = settings.Issuer,
                ValidAudience = settings.Audience,
                IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Key)
            };
        });
```

and after that add app.UseAuthentication();

Answer (score 0):

Following up on @Tseng's comment, I downloaded the reference code from Github and removed the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer package, sure enough I got the error "The type or namespace name could not be found" for both UseJwtBearerAuthentication and JwtBearerOptions.

When re-installing the package, I noted that **the latest version will fail to install** - I tried version 1.1.1 and it installed and gave me a successful build.